# Uber API: The network connection was lost

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm attempting to connect to the Uber API in my app Dude Where's My Car?.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.uber.com/v1/products"]];
NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token 5T_nIOG9wkV-9GpbFf8mXNTIcHOJPM79UCwkQfJ9"];
[request setHTTPBody:[@"latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

This ObjC code yields the following error:
Connection failed! Error - The network connection was lost. https://api.uber.com/v1/products

I've run the Python sample app and curl in the terminal with no such errors.

Please help me diagnose this problem. It will surely help other developers!

Thanks,
Holp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any problems with the Uber API.  Here are some monitored examples, including the Products API you are calling:

https://www.restytesty.com/projects/uber-api-examples

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was adding the parameters in the URL. Like this:

```
NSURL *products = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=%f&longitude=%f&server_token=%@", latitude,longitude,UBER_SERVERTOKEN]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:products];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

I know this is wrong but it's the only way I could make it work. Hope it helps you.